# YouTube iFrame player : this video is restricted from being viewed on this domain

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

[image: YouTube Player Error]

I got the above error when I embed a YouTube iFrame player on my site when you try to play any video.

You can try by yourself to see the error on this test page : https://you.dj/test.php

In my test page, I just embed the YouTube player by using the standard HTML embed code provided by YouTube :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GEZhD3J89ZE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Some Google results mentioned that this error could be related to the YouTube API terms. About that I just recently got a complete YouTube API audit and actually the error appeared over night 5 days after the beginning of that audit. HOWEVER the YouTube audit team ensured me that my site respects the YouTube terms and they are not aware of blocking on my site.

My use of YouTube is pretty simple, I just use the YouTube Data API to list YouTube videos and I also embed YouTube iFrame players in various pages. But to be sure, I removed all YouTube API calls and iFrame players in my site (except test page) to see if it does something, but no luck.

The error doesn't happen with the Brave browser so it has to do with the ETag or cookies I guess. It looks like when the YouTube iFrame player requests the actual video, YouTube server replies :

> error=0.504:auth:0.000:ec.150;ed.0;es.This%20video%20is%20restricted%20from%20being%20viewed%20on%20this%20domain.;a6s.3

My Google API console doesn't show any issue and my YouTube API Quota is set very high.

Can you someone have an idea how to solve this? I am an experienced web programmer but I am stuck... Thanks!

ps : maybe related to : [Why does Youtube API show video unavailable when trying to load it onto my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018380/why-does-youtube-api-show-video-unavailable-when-trying-to-load-it-onto-my-site)

Comment: Try with another video - and try while you're loged with a YouTube account. [See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtvhQ6klunk) - it might help. I also saw a settings in the parameter or request where you add the url of your domain...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as I said in the first sentence, this error appears for ALL videos. Also this error appears for all users of the app :/. I really have no idea of what's happening...